# Apache Superset make one value for multiple options in filter box

Tags: sql, apache-superset

I am using Apache Superset to visualize data in a DB.

The Filter Box is used to filter data. It is necessary to group several values into one in order to filter by several values at once when you select one value. For example, select "SMM" and get data at once for all values associated with "SMM" (youtube, instagram, vk, facebook)

I tried through custom settings using SQL, but that did not solve my question, since the filter understands the SMM value as a parameter and not as a reference to other values:

```
SELECT *,
CASE 
  WHEN column_name in ('value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4') then 'SMM'
END as column_name_agg
FROM db.name
```